# Authorization & Capture for no paypal users

Tags: paypal, capture, express-checkout, authorize

Is Authorization & Capture payal feature available for users who don't have a paypal account? Is it mandatory for my users to have an account? I have a business account. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tested this on the sandbox and it works just fine running an authorization with guest checkout.

You do need to make sure you have "PayPal Account Optional" enabled in your PayPal profile, and then you need to make sure and include SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing in your SetExpressCheckout request.

This will give the users the ability to checkout with guest checkout (credit card without creating a PayPal account) and you can do Auth & Capture just fine this way based on my tests.

Comment: And is it possible with a digital goods account? Or Payments Pro is the only way?

Comment: I'll have to double check my original answer here.  Now that I think about it I'm not entirely confident in what I said.  I'll run a test in the sandbox a little later to see if I'm able to go ahead and do a Guest checkout through EC as an Authorization.  Of course, you can always test that yourself, too, if you don't want to wait on me.

Comment: I wanted to do that test, but my paypal consultat told me the sandbox is not so reliable for such operations...

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a new PayPal consultant.  That's exactly what the sandbox is for and it's perfect for that sort of operation.

Comment: I believe so... :) Anyway, tomorrow i will setup my sandbox account and try to do the test (i am a paypal newbie, so it could took a while before i do it). In the meantime if you have some news, please let me now. Thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and tested this in the sandbox and it worked just fine.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But now I am a little confused, as state here developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/…, to do auth and capture using API, paymentaction must be authorization (paymentaction=authorization) and not Sale...am I missing something?

Comment: No, that's correct.  You just set the action to Authorization for both SEC and DECP.